# What happens if two ? after php url

Tags: php, parameters

What happens if a URL link is like this

http://abc.com/123.php?p=1?source=yahoo&key=56

can 123.php retrieve all parameters?

Comment: After the first question mark, any other question mark is interpreted as "normal" character.

Comment: @phil I would think its been down voted because it is a simple matter for the OP to check this himself, hence it "does not show any research effort". That's why I down voted it anyway. -1

Comment: @vascoshite which is perfectly understandable; just tell him that.

Comment: Meh, I upvoted. A 10 second google search for the answer is faster than a 5-10 minute research session (depending on your configuration/server set up). These little 5-10 minute tests could add up to hours of lost productivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`p` will gone, you should do

```
$url = 'http://abc.com/123.php?'.urlencode('p=1?source=yahoo&key=56');
```

Answer (score 2):

In PHP $_GET will hold the following ( result of [var_dump($_GET)](http://my.php.net/var_dump) )

```
array(2) { ["p"]=> string(14) "1?source=yahoo" ["key"]=> string(2) "56" }
```

If you want to use the question mark (or other reserved chars) use [urlencode](http://my.php.net/urlencode)

Answer (score 0):

No. I don't think that's a valid query string.

Answer (score 0):

Test it yourself with:

```
print_r($_GET);
```

I tested it an I get:

> Array ( [p] => 1?source=yahoo [key] => 56 )

If you have control over the string appended to the url use [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

Answer (score 0):

From the [RFC 1738 - Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html):

> only alphanumerics, the special characters `$-_.+!*'(),`, and reserved characters used for their reserved purposes may be used unencoded within a URL.

The character `?` is a reserved character.  Since the URL you give is not using it for its reserved purpose (separating the "path" from the "searchpart"), the URL is illegal, and you shouldn't rely on any particular behaviour.

Encode the `?` character, and ensure that the URL is legal if you want predictable behaviour.